# How to stop execution when my assertion is passed?

Tags: selenium, testng, assertion

How to stop execution when my assertion passed? I have written driver.quit, but  code is executed after that.

```
try {
    //....
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    //Screenshot.captureScreenshot(driver,"KeyInstn"+keyInstn); 
    Assert.assertEquals("pass", "pass"); 
    //Assert.Pass(); 
    driver.quit();
} 
String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle(); 
// To handle all new opened window. 
Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();
```

Comment: you want to fail test or to stop process or return success? can you show your code?

Comment: I want to stop further running the script.I have provided driver.quit().

Comment: but  test script is executed further and am getting org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?..... since i have made the driver.quit

Comment: why do you have code after assertion if you don't want to execute it? (if assert failed you stop and also if it succeeded)

Comment: catch (Exception e) 
       {
        //Screenshot.captureScreenshot(driver,"KeyInstn"+keyInstn);
        Assert.assertEquals("pass", "pass");
        //Assert.Pass();
        driver.quit();
        }
    
 
     
     String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();  
           
           // To handle all new opened window.    
               Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();  
           Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();

Comment: In a case where there is no data for an input, i want to pass it.if there is data i want to validate it.

Comment: Is there an assertpass?? which can pass my script and stop further processing the script??

Comment: Your question is unclear, you should edit your question with all the details, maybe your are looking for `assertNotEquals`

Comment: How to pass a testcase and stop further execution?Is there an assert which can pass any  testcase and stop further execution

Comment: To fail a testcase and stop further execution we have asserts. How about to pass a testcase and stop further execution, what asserts do we have?

Comment: To have a test pass after an assert, you don't have code after the assert. Your scenario is not clear. A simple `if-then` seems like it would take care of it but there's not enough detail to understand what you want to happen in each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you provided, you do not need an assert after `driver.quit();` to stop execution. Simply add a `return;` after that line and method execution stops.

If that code is from within a test method, the test case ends without error.